# PC goes to sleep instead of hibernation

Tags: sleep, hibernate

This is my first question in this forum, so please excuse me if I missed anything.

Problem Statement:
Selecting Hibernate option from the shutdown options, the PC will go to Sleep instead of hibernation.

OS: Windows 11

Hyper-sleep option is OFF

Comment: Thank John, unfortunately, did not work

Answer (score 1):

Try enabling *hibernate* from the CMD prompt.

- Press <kbd>Windows</kbd>, type `CMD`, and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> to get a CMD prompt with Administrative rights.
- Enter `powercfg -h on` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to enable hibernation.
- Test that it works by entering `shutdown /h` and pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>. The PC should hibernate, if it is capable of doing so. Check that the power light is fully off, and that it returns from hibernation to where you were, afterwards.

If this does *not* work, check that wake timers are disabled.

[image: Disable Wake Timers]

Comment: Thanks DrMoishe Pippik, it didn't work.